# Segmentation fault on dd command

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, linux-kernel, dd

I ran this command on Ubuntu to resize the `/tmp` and after that there is segmentation fault coming.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/xvda1 bs=1024M count=2
```

Its our live server. Is there any way to get it working or get the data?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you unmount /tmp before resize and *dd* ?

Comment: not really ... I was not aware about and ran it accidentyl .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The segmentation fault was probably related to the selected block size: with `bs=1024M` you asked for 1GB-sized blocks, which can be too much for your server.

Anyway, if `xvda1` was your data partition, unfortunately your data are gone. Sorry...